# not found FirebaseInitProvider in android

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have a problem on android not found (com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider), but I don't use google firebase in my code?

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
      compileSdkVersion 25
      buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

      defaultConfig {
             applicationId "XXXXXXXXXXXX"
             minSdkVersion 14
             targetSdkVersion 25
             versionCode 21
             versionName "1.0.10"
             multiDexEnabled true
             testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
      }

      buildTypes {
                release {
                      minifyEnabled false
                      proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
                }
     }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'
compile project(':showcase')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

}
```

> 02-19 15:07:45.137 25956-25956/XXXXXXXX E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                         Process: XXXXXXXX, PID: 25956
>                                                                         java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider
>   com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path:
>   DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/XXXXXXXX-7.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/XXXXXXXX-7,
>   /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
>                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5202)
>                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4794)
>                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4734)
>                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:166)
>                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1343)
>                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5590)
>                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                                             at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1280)
>                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1096)
>                                                                             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                                                                          Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path:
>   DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/XXXXXXXX-7.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/XXXXXXXX-7,
>   /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
>                                                                             at
>   dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>                                                                             at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
>                                                                             at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
>                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5187)
>                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4794) 
>                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4734) 
>                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:166) 
>                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1343) 
>                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
>                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5590) 
>                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
>                                                                             at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1280) 
>                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1096) 
>                                                                             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: FYI-  that's not the real Volley you're using.  Its someone's mirror, who may not be up to date or may have malicious code.  You should use the official Google version.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're including the entire Google Play Services which in 10.0.1 also have Firebase as their dependencies.
Try running *./gradlew :app:dependencies* to see the complete dependency tree

You should limit your Google Play Dependencies to only those you actually need. See https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Also, you shouldn't be using two different play services versions

> compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
>
> compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'